# save time.time() in django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to have some kind of timestsamp for updating of models. The problem is that mysql timestamp is only in 1 sec resolution, so if I use DateTime with auto_add_now this is not fine enough for me.

I thought of using float field and to assign it to time.time() on every update. This is a model where I use update using QuerySet.update()

```
model MyModel:
  last_update = models.FloatField(default=time.time)
```

I then take care of updating last_update before any save (all my calls goes through central location, so I can do this explicitly in the creation), e.g something like:

```
m = MyModel(..,last_update=time.time())
```

or when I do bulk update,

```
m = MyModel.objects.filter(....).update(last_update_time=time.time())
```

Are there any issues with this approach of saving float and order by it?

Just to clarify, I'm aware of DateTimeField option with auto_now=True, the problem is that this gives me 1 second resolution since it is mapped to date time field in MYSQL which is 1 sec resolution (I'm using MYSQL 5.5)

Comment: Why do you need fraction of a second accuracy? What are you trying to do with the field? That may give better insight to what you want.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `DateField.auto_now`, and the field will be updated each time the object gets saved. For example `last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)`.

You can read the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield), as you can see that Field option is intended to archive exactly what you want.

Also you can override the `save` method as you can see [there](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield) and update the `last_update` field as you prefer.

Personally I recommend the first approach because of simplicity, there is also a third option using signals but I guess that can get so confusing.

Answer (score 1):

```
 from datetime import datetime

 class Model(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField()

 def save(self):
    if self.date_created == None:
       self.date_created = datetime.now()
    self.date_modified = datetime.now()
    super(Model, self).save()
```

Comment: Datetimes from `datetime` package are not TZ aware, so that dates will not localize well. It's better to use `django.utils.timezone`.

Comment: thanks. I'm aware of this option, the problem is that by using DateTimeField I'm getting 1 sec resolution which is what I wanted to avoid from.